# I'm using google oauth with React js and it is loading google account and after i click on my profile popup get closed

Tags: reactjs, google-oauth

I'm using google oauth with React js and it is loading google account and 
after i click on my profile popup get closed.

my code chunk

```
<GoogleLogin
clientId={GCLIENT_ID}
buttonText="Google Login"
onSuccess={() => this.googleResponse}
onFailure={() => this.googleResponse}
cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
/>
```

Tried all suggestions given on the net. Still it seems not working. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

`onSucces={() => this.googleResponse}` does not call your `googleResponse` method, it returns it to the caller of the function.

I recommend you change your code as follows:

```
<GoogleLogin
    onSuccess={this.googleResponse}
    onFailure={this.googleResponse}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response ! Still facing the same issue.

Comment: Thats because nothing more has to happen with the window. You get a response with your `googleResponse` method that you have to handle on your own. You should read up on [Google OAuth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

Comment: Thanks ! I'll check it.